# Whats the difference between func(160.0-90.0) and func((160.0-90.0)) (macro)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm clueless, why two extra braces when giving parameters to a macro have different results.

Given the following macro:

```
#define   DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees)  ((M_PI * degrees)/ 180)
```

Why the following code:

```
NSLog(@"test 1: %f", DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(70.0));
NSLog(@"test 2: %f", DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(160.0-90.0));
NSLog(@"test 3: %f", DEGREES_TO_RADIANS((160.0-90.0)));
```

Has different results:

```
2012-12-05 00:43:07.177 test[9267:11603] test 1: 1.221730
2012-12-05 00:43:07.179 test[9267:11603] test 2: 2.292527
2012-12-05 00:43:07.180 test[9267:11603] test 3: 1.221730
```

Test 1 & 3 are correct. But why 'test 2' has a *wrong* answer, beats me. Maybe one of guru's can shed some light on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `M_PI * 160.0 - 90.0` != `M_PI * (160.0-90.0)`

This is precisely why it is highly recommended to write the macro with parentheses:

```
#define   DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees)  ((M_PI * (degrees))/ 180)
```

Comment: Yep, the macro was incorrectly written.  As indicated, the macro author should always surround parms with `()` characters in case the parameter is not a simple token.